# Custom Taxonomy - fields

Tags: custom-post-types, php, wp-query, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I have a custom taxonomy called projects that has a custom post type called apartments, both have acf custom fields.

I want to bring the taxonomy created projects with their acf fields on a certain page, example project 1, project 2.

I have created taxonomy-projects_apartments.php and used it as a template, for a page called projects.

```
$args = array(
    'taxonomy'     => 'projects',
    'orderby'      => $orderby,
    'show_count'   => $show_count,
    'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
    'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
    'title_li'     => $title
);

wp_list_categories( $args );
```

This only brings the names, project 1 and project 2. On the single project page I use:

```
$queried_object = get_queried_object();
$taxonomy = $queried_object->taxonomy;
$term_id = $queried_object->term_id;

// load content for this taxonomy term
$custom_field = get_field('insert_new_project', 'projects' . '_' . $term_id);
```

to bring custom fields, and it works.

But queried objects brings the current page object, and does not work in the way I needed it to.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: What's the stored data in `%term_meta` table against the `$term_id` in database? Sort 'em _there_ first, then try the ACF. It'll make the process less buggy.

Comment: OK, wait... So what exactly are you trying to achieve? What custom fields are there? What objects are there assigned for? And where do you want to display what...?

Comment: Updated code:                                                                                                           $newargs = array(
         'post_type' => 'apartamente',
         'tax_query' => array(
          array(
           'taxonomy' => 'projects',
           'field' => 'slug',
          )
         )
        );

        $the_query2 = new WP_Query( $newargs );

Answer (score 0):

Updated code:

```
                                                                                                       $newargs = array(
        'post_type' => 'apartments',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'projects',
                'field' => 'slug',
            )
        )
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $newargs );



<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

 //The query returns 0, if I use a taxonomy, for post types it works, and I can bring all ACF fields to that post. But I want also want taxonomy acf fields here.
<?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

//Custom field that Is inserted into apartments custom post type

 <?php while ( have_rows( 'assign_apartment_project') ) : the_row(); ?>


<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```